# Database error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, odbc

I am running [SMS Enabler](http://smsenabler.com/) software in a Windows 7 environment. When a message received, the database is not updating and gives the error.

> Database error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I also added the required field in **`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) > User DSN`**

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.... If test connection succeeds and your app fails then it is probably one of those awkward environment issues..

Things to check -

- Have you creates a System DSN or User DSN?

  If your application is running as a System Service then it will only able to read System DSNs (not User DSNs)
- Was the Driver installed for all users or just the installation user?

  I have seen instances where this has affected some drivers...
- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (an excellent tool for tracking down issues like this)

  If you haven't used Process Monitor - think of it as a sniffer for; file accesses, registry accesses and network access...

  That is - you will be able to determine whether there are any files or registry accesses that are failing or being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the help again Garry. I'll try that one. Meanwhile I have used Ozeki SMS server and I did what I wanted to do. There the database connected nice and easily.

Answer (score 1):

To use SMS Enabler with MySQL you should install [MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html) **32-bit**. You should install 32-bit version of this connector even if you are on 64 bit Windows. This is because SMS Enabler is a 32-bit software.

Comment: I am using following connections string in my asp.net application:
 <add name="MyODBCString" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};SERVER=someserver.amazonaws.com;DATABASE=mydb2017;PORT=3306;USER=testuser;PASSWORD=testuser;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
this works on server but not on local machine which version should i install on local machine? even if driver mentioned in connection string is 'ODBC 5.2 ANSI ' should i install 5.1 ?? Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Wondering *again* whether this is a 32/64bit issue?

There are two ODBC administrators on 64bit machines...

c:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe === 64bit === Also through Control Panel

c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe === 32bit

If your application is 32bit then you need a 32bit ODBC Driver and have to create a 32bit ODBC data source.

If your application is 64bit then, similarly, you need a 64bit ODBC Driver and have to create a 64bit ODBC data source.

I am wondering whether your application is 32bit and hence cannot find the 64bit ODBC data source you have created...

(NOTE: all of this is only applicable on 64bit Windows OSs...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Garry. 
I have double checked, my Windows 7 OS type is 32-bit and I have installed odbcad32.exe
After I have made the connection and click on the "Test" button, I'm getting "Success..." message. But I think the software that I am using is unable to connect with that database. I suppose I have completed the configuration of that software in an accurate way.